# Using Python and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am doing a CA and I have to parse the page using beautiful soup, I did with the code

```
r = urlopen(url)    # download the page
res1 = str(r.read()) # put the content into a variable
soup = BeautifulSoup(res1,'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

but then I have to print how many different pages have been crawled.

Is anybody has a tip to give me ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Only one page is crawled in this code

Comment: your comment says it all `# download the **page**`

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to "put" the content into a variable like you do in line 2. You can just call it like `soup = BeautifulSoup(res1.read(),'html.parser')`

Comment: You don't even have to call `read`, `BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), ...)` is sufficient - BeautifulSoup accepts file-like objects.

Comment: "I am doing a CA..." --- Certificate Authority?  Collision Analysis?  College Application?  Heavy Cruiser?

Comment: you crawled only 1 page like cricket_007 said and as written in your code comment...

Answer (score 0):

As @cricket_007 mentioned in the comments, your current code 'crawls' (i.e. retrieves) only one page.

If you need to print how many links did you find in the document, you can just do

```
print(len(soup.find_all('a')))
```

Note that `soup.find_all('a')` is a list of the corresponding tags, so it's `len` gives you a number of links.

If you really need to crawl website (e.g. to retrieve page, get all links from this page, follow every of these links, retrieve the page it refers to and so on), I'd suggest using [RoboBrowser](http://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/) instead of "pure" BeautifulSoup.